# How to handle > (&gt;) symbol in Django forms

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-forms

In my MySQL table row (UTF-8) I have both `&gt;` and `<`. The `<` is used for html and the `&gt;` is for text within the html.

The problem is, is that I keep getting the error:

> DjangoUnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3

What should I do?

Comment: I don't think your error is caused by having &gt; or < in your MySQL table. Django is trying to decode a byte that isn't valid utf-8.

Comment: Ahh yes. So how do I tell django that there is a difference!?